# Directly using an image url for Iframe src attribute

Tags: html, iframe

I usually using an Iframe with src pointing to a HTML file containing an image:

Iframe

```
<iframe src="/image.html">
```

Image.html

```
<img src="/hello.jpg">
```

However, one time I accidentally used the image path in the Iframe

```
<iframe src="/hello.jpg">
```

And it still work perfectly. Is it a normal way to use this method? I am considering if there will be any inconsistent problem on different browsers / or does this method officially allowed in HTML.

Thanks.